# Uniqueness of Ruby Instances

Tags: ruby, instance

If I create two String instances with the same content separately they are identical. This is not the case with custom classes by default (see example below).

If I have my own class (`Test` below) and I have a variable (`@v` below) which is unique, ie. two `Test` instances with the same `@v` should be treated as identical, then how would I go about telling Ruby this is the case?

Consider this example:

```
class Test
  def initialize(v)
    @v = v
  end
end

a = {Test.new('a') => 1, Test.new('b') => 2}

a.delete(Test.new('a'))

p a
# # Desired output:
# => {#<Test:0x100124ef8 @v="b">=>2}
```

Comment: Two string instances with the same content are not identical. `"string".equal?("string")` returns `false`

Comment: Ahh, my mistake. I assumed they were because `a = {'string' => 'a string'}; a.delete('string')` works!

Comment: @JP: I think hashes has a special case if they use a string as a key.

Comment: @Andrew Grimm: No, strings as hash keys are compared using `#hash` and `#eql?` just like any other object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a different way to tackle this, by keeping track of all the instances of Test internally I can return the premade instance rather than making a new one and telling ruby they're equivalent:

```
class Test
  def self.new(v)
    begin
      return @@instances[v] if @@instances[v]
    rescue
    end

    new_test = self.allocate
    new_test.instance_variable_set(:@v,v)
    (@@instances ||= {})[v] = new_test
  end
end
```

Now `Test.new('a') == Test.new('a')` *and* `Test.new('a') === Test.new('a')` :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to define an `==` method that defines what equality means for your class. In this case, you would want:

```
class Test
  def initialize(v)
    @v = v
  end
  def ==(other)
    @v == other.instance_variable_get(:@v)
  end
end
```

Comment: Fantastic, thanks! this will definitely work, but if I change an attribute on `a1 = Test.new('a')` will it also be apparent on `a2 = Test.new('a')`? I really want them to *be* the same object, not just equate.

Comment: Oops, I spoke too quickly, adding that `==` method to my example above doesn't actually give the desired output - sorry!

Answer (score 1):

You are using objects of class `Test` as keys for the hash. In order for that to function properly (and consequently `a.delete`), you need to define two methods inside Test: `Test#hash` and `Test#eql?`

From: http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Hash.html

> Hash uses key.eql? to test keys for
>   equality. If you need to use instances
>   of your own classes as keys in a Hash,
>   it is recommended that you define both
>   the eql? and hash methods. The hash
>   method must have the property that
>   a.eql?(b) implies a.hash == b.hash.

Answer (score 1):

Most of the time, an object you need to be comparable and/or hashable is composed of member variables which are either primitives (integers, strings, etc) or are themselves comparable/hashable.  In those cases, this module:

```
module Hashable

  include Comparable

  def ==(other)
    other.is_a?(self.class) && other.send(:parts) == parts
  end
  alias_method :eql?, :==

  def hash
    parts.hash
  end

end
```

can simply be included in your class to take care of all of the busywork.  All you have to do is define a "parts" method that returns all of the values that comprise the object's state:

```
class Foo

  include Hashable

  def initialize(a, b)
    @a = a
    @b = b
  end

  private

  def parts
    [@a, @b]
  end

end
```

Objects built this way are comparable (they have <, <=, ==, >=, >, != and equ?) and they can be hash keys.